# Teamcity - last commit author and comment - pass into ant script

Tags: svn, ant, teamcity, svnkit

How to pass svn last commit author and comment to ant build script, invoked via Teamcity runner?

Comment: created http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/TW-16841

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make use of `%system.build.vcs.number%` and pass it as parameter to the ANT build file or read the environment variable set by TeamCity - `%env.BUILD_VCS_NUMBER%` ( the environment variable to be read will be `BUILD_VCS_NUMBER`) in the build file.

Use that along with the `%vcsroot.url%` to get the author and the commit message ( you can choose different vcs roots using their names like `%vcsroot.name.url%`